# Why can't functions defined in Drupal blocks access globals?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

Scenario:  I've defined a custom block in Drupal 6.20 under PHP 5.2.14.  I've enabled PHP Code and I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
<?php
  $a = "success";

  function test() {
    global $a;

    print $a;
  }

  test();
?>
```

It prints nothing on my system, because I cannot seem to scope variable $a.  I've also tried $GLOBALS['a'] to no avail.  What gives?  I feel like I'm going crazy.

Incidentally, using the global keyword in the outer scope will happily make drupal's globals available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not hugely familiar with Drupal but I'm guessing that the blocks are included inside some other function/method somewhere, so you're effectively dealing with a nested function, the include being in that outer function's local scope.

With that, it makes sense that `$a = "success"` can't be addressed from within the `test()` function.

If I'm right, it should work if you slap the `global` keyword on *both* scopes.

Comment: You are quite correct, Sir!  Thank you for helping me find some sanity over here.

Comment: @mkoistinen you're welcome, I've been pulling my hair about this too.